# How to set MSDN in order to open on a certain version of Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

In a network, there are certain different installed versions of Microsoft SQL Server, starting with 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2.

Is there a specific option of MSDN that can fix the opening of new pages on the version of SQL Server that is being worked on?

For instance, can I set MSDN to open on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, if I work only on that version?

EDIT in order to clarify what I am asking:

1. When a user searches the Internet using a search engine for the syntax of a specific SQL statement, he might get to a MSDN web page such as the following one, which presents the "SELECT (Transact-SQL)" SQL statement:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

2. Even if the user is logged in the MSDN system using a user name such as "UserName123", there are no apparent settings - or maybe I have not found them yet - so that the version of the Microsoft SQL Server can be pre-set. Currently, always the pages open with the latest version, which is "SQL Server 2014".
3. In this situation, the user has to select from the "Other Versions" drop-down list his preferred Microsoft SQL Server version, for instance "SQL Server 2005". There are cases when the user forgets to do that and reads the syntax for a version of Microsoft SQL Server that he is not interested in.
4. Finally, the question: Is it possible to automatically pre-set somehow, using any MSDN user configuration settings, the Microsoft SQL Server version that is automatically chosen when displaying information?

Comment: By MSDN, are you asking about opening your browser to Books OnLine documentation for the appropriate version of your SQL Server Version? If so, what if you have a mixed installation on the machine?

Comment: @billinkc : Yes, through MSDN I meant a web page such as [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335(v=sql.90).aspx) where the `INSERT` (`Transact-SQL`) statement is described.

The current situation is mixed only up to the point where the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio client is version 2008 R2, while the database server where the user connects is version 2005. By using a `SELECT @@VERSION` statement, I can see where the user goes.

Still, I noticed that MSDN normally opens at the latest version (these days, 2014) and sometimes the user gets stuck.

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible - however I would suggest leveraging the `F1` hotkey in SSMS when the cursor is over a word you want to look up, which will let you access the locally installed BOL (which you can manage to only have the relevant version) or the appropriate page online for the version of SSMS you're using.

Comment: The other approach I'd propose is make 6 bookmarks, covering 2000 - 2014, and put that on a network share. New server, add it to the All Users/Default Users bookmarks. If you absolutely must eliminate thinking in the users mind, I'm sure a wee bit of PowerShell could correlate the SQL Server version to the bookmark file and only import the appropriate one. But seriously, that's a terrible idea. If you're responsible for the administration of my servers, you'd darn well better have your thinking hat on

Comment: Thank you for commenting, @billinkc. Probably scripting would save the day, again. Initially, I thought that by querying a search engine with a search text string such as "`sql server 2005 select into`", one would get the corresponding MSDN web page, that is, from the 2005 version of Microsoft SQL Server. Since one cannot rely on a search engine such as Google to do the trick - and since I have not found yet any MSDN user configuration settings at all -, probably some MS-DOS Batch files or Microsoft PowerShell would be helpful.

Comment: At the end of the day this all seems to me that any solution requires more effort, planning, and general hackery than is worth it compared to educating a user to perform an extra two clicks. I mean, *everyone* else deals with it already, yknow?

Comment: @John: The question has arisen after being asked about a particular problem that was supposedly not working, although it was apparently conforming to some syntax. After spending a quarter of hour attempting all of the possible tricks needed in order to find a solution for the so-called problem, by some luck I have tested it on another configuration, with the right version of Microsoft SQL Server. So, yes, indeed, I have to first educate myself to check whatever the user did not attempt to check in the very first place.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a thrown-together hack with what I had on hand. If you don't have Fiddler installed, you'll need to get it from http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Set it to `Keep: 100 sessions` then go to the AutoResponder tab and add this rule:

If request matches: `regex:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms(\d+)(\(v=sql.(100|105|110)\))?.aspx`

Then respond with: `*redir:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms$1(v=sql.90).aspx`

If you'd like to use a different version of SQL Server, then change the number at the end of the Respond With string and make sure to take that number out of the If Request Matches string or you'll end up in a redirect loop.

`Enable rules` and check `Unmatched requests passthrough`. Fiddler will have to capture traffic (`F12`) in order for this to function. The configuration screen should look like this:

[image: Fiddler settings]